# CocoaPods referencing Frameworks and Static Libs aren't working for me

Tags: xcode, static-libraries, cocoapods, symbols, xcode-workspace

I've included " pod 'NewRelicAgent' " (framework) and " pod 'Helpshift' " (.a static lib) but both of these complain about missing symbols at compile time.  I can specfically see that the HelpShift lib.a that is present in the file system (after "pod install") does not show in the Pod project for the HelpShift pod.

All of my other pods that I use include their .h/.m files and compile just fine.  In the mean time, I've simply manually copied my required static libs over into another directory.

I've read all the documentation/stackoverflow I can find on static library pods.  No one seems to mention difficulty getting these to work.

I'm using the latest Xcode 5.1.1 and "pod --version" is 0.33.1 and "rvm --version" is ruby-2.0.0-p481

I'm building for architectures armv7, armv7s, arm64

Comment: Do you have ${inherited} in 'OTHER LINKER FLAGS' in your target project?
What is the architecture you are building for ?

Comment: It's been a while...  I am including $(inherited) where it may not have been previously....  things seem to be working now.  Write your comment as an answer and I'll accept it.